# How can I run a maven build in a cycle in jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple maven job in Jenkins which runs in windows agents, in total I have 50 windows agents in which the script must be executed, the problem is that I have to do it manually, which means that whenever I build a job and it terminates, then I have to rebuild the job and change the agent where it last ran ( see the screenshots) for example, job1 runs on agent windows01, and job ends it has to run on agent windows02, windows03, etc, but I want to do this in an automatic way not manually.

[image: jenkins builds]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [matrix](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/):

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Agent matrix') {
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'agent'
                        values 'windows01', 'windows02', 'windows03' // , ...
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Run') {
                        steps {
                            node( "$agent" ) {
                                sh "echo Running on $agent..."
                            }
                        }
                    } // stage 'Run'
                }
            } // matrix
        } // stage 'Agent matrix'
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i add this code?

Comment: @AdrianJimenez See [Getting started with Pipeline – Defining a Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#defining-a-pipeline). If yo don't use `Jenkinsfile`s you can create a project of type _Multi-configuration project_ (and then the [tag:jenkins-pipeline] tag on your question is misleading).